# Ionic menu toggling caused page to not displaying property

Tags: ionic-framework

Page displayed correctly when it is open. However some elements become not visible when I toggle the menu. Things such as icon, text, images.

```
 >ionic info
 ordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a temp fix for people also having this problem. 

I found out the problem only happens when you scroll down then open the menu.
So all I did is to use [scrollToTop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/) method when user taps the menu.

 still waiting on the real solution.